# How to add history and favorites feature in Windows Phone 8 web app?

Tags: c#, browser, windows-phone-8, browser-history, favorites

I am building a web browser for Windows Phone 8.
Now I have done the basic thing like back, forward, refresh etc,
but I want to add two more features which will make it complete.

First a history feature, that records the history of visited web pages and display it later when asked.

Secondly, I want to add a favorites features where the current web page on the browser can be put in the list and later the list can be viewed.

I found something helpful on this but it was for wpf and didn't work so can anybody can tell me step by step what to do with code or example?
I can also post the sample code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Navigation History**

Handle ***Navigated*** Event of WebBrowser control and in event handler and save the Url in text format in Isolated Storage file. below is the code.

in your xaml

```
<phone:WebBrowser Navigated="WebBrowser_Navigated" ... >
```

Event Handler in code behind

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storeFile= IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Browse_History.txt", FileMode.Append, storeFile));
            sr.WriteLine(e.Uri.ToString());
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Below method will read browser history from local store

```
private List<string> ReadHistory()
    {
        List<string> history = new List<string>();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storeFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (storeFile.FileExists("Browse_History.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Browse_History.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, storeFile)))
                {
                    var uri = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
                    {
                        history.Add(uri);
                        uri = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    return history;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You will have to add some missing assemblies using statements at the top

```
 using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
 using System.IO;
```

**2. Favorties**

I suppose you want to save favorites on a button click with current opened page Url. On button click event handler write following code.

```
    private void btnSaveToFavorties_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     using (IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Browser_Favorties.txt", FileMode.Append, appStore));
            sr.WriteLine(webBrowser.Source.ToString());
            sr.Close();
        }
 }
```

and below is the code for loading all favorties

```
private List<string> LoadFavoirties()
    {
        List<string> history = new List<string>();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (appStorage.FileExists("Browser_Favorties.txt"))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Browser_Favorties.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, appStorage)))
                {
                    var uri = reader.ReadLine();
                    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
                    {
                        history.Add(uri);
                        uri = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    return history;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How will i diplay the save list of history and favourites